# Find and hide text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am trying to restyle elements of a website that uses JavaServer Pages (.jsp) but without having to set up a fully functional environment. So I have a template file which brings in the .jsp files with:

```
<!--#include virtual="fileDirectory/file.jsp"-->
```

This works fine for what I need, but the problem is there are lines of code in the .jsp files that look like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="front" prefix="front" %>
```

These lines simply render as text and completely mess up the layout. Is there a way, using JavaScript or jQuery, to select strings that start with <%@ and end with %> so that I can hide them?

Comment: I would look into regex

Comment: why don't you remove than?

Comment: I can't remove them because they will be re-uploaded to the server, and there are nearly 700 of these files!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will replace all portions of the `body` html that starts with `<%@` and ends with `%>`.

```
$("body").html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/&lt;%@[^%>]+%&gt;/gi, "");
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rkh6rb6d/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, does exactly what I need it to!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker) to traverse the text nodes and replace any that contain '*%@ taglib...*':

```js
(function walk() {
    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);
    var node;
    while(node = walker.nextNode()) {
        if(node.nodeValue.indexOf("%@ taglib")>0){
            node.nodeValue = "";
        }
    }
})();
```

```html
<b>abc</b>
<%@ taglib uri="front" prefix="front" %>
<b>def</b>
```